# Need to trust all the certificates during the development using Spring

Tags: java, spring, ssl, configuration

I read this very useful [article](http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html) about disabling all the https certificates programmatically. I need such approach only in the development. And I'm using Spring. So does anybody have ideas about how can I do the same thing just in spring context files, not in the Java code?
I mean this particular part of code:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

Actually, I can simulate the first line:
something like that:

```
<bean id="sslContext"
        class="javax.net.ssl.SSLContext"
      factory-method="getInstance">
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="SSL" />
    </bean>
```

Also, I can create this trustAllCerts bean.
But... I confused.. it is possible to call a some method of a bean in spring context initialization? I mean how can I call sc.init and sc.getSocketFactory in spring context file? Is it impossible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can use `init-method` attribute. Look at [Initialization callbacks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle). But this interface is not enough. I suggest simply placing this code

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```

In your custom class which will know that you are in dev mode or wchich will have such init-method. 
BTW calling `getSocketFactory` is simple - this is simply getting `socketFactory` property.

Comment: If we are constrained to use a config file, it would be nice to see how to do this in a config file with dependency injection.