# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager: How to do Https requests?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpcomponents, truststore

I'm currently trying to do multiple `HttpGet` requests at the same time with `CloseableHttpClient`.
I googled on how to do that and the answer was to use a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

At this point I got this:

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionManager(cManager)
    .build();
```

Then I tried a `HttpGet` request to `http://www.google.com` and everything worked fine.

Then I created a truststore via cmd and imported the certificate of the targeted website, setup a `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` with my truststore and set the `SSLSocketFactory` of `httpClient`:

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("myTrustStore.truststore"));
trustStore.load(inputStream, "nopassword".toCharArray());
inputStream.close();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
    .setConnectionManager(cManager)
    .build();
```

If I try to execute a Https `HttpGet` then I get a `PKIX path building failed` exception.
If I do the same without `.setConnectionManager(cManager)` everything works fine.

Can anyone of you tell me how I can get this to work? (Don't worry, I don't create any ddos tool)

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I'm using HttpComponents 4.3.1

Comment: ` CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
    .setConnectionManager(cManager)
    .build(); `
Setting SSLSocketFacotry() here is not useful here as the socket factory set inside the connectionmanager via registry is used.  So when when you set connection manager, no need to set sslsocketfactory() while building client

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950935/1223253

Just had to add

```
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create().register("https", sslsf).build();
```

and pass `socketFactoryRegistry` as parameter to the constructor of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.
Now it works just fine :)

Comment: How to use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager after creating this , my code is working but i want to know does connection pooling works or not

Comment: turn on client logging to check leases from the connection pool: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: great, I spent 2 days on this, and with your help it got resolved in 5 minutes. 
I wish if I could I have seen this earlier..
Thank You.

Comment: If you want 'http' as well as 'https', check this comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20491564/3010484