# how to make Unirest(java) ignore certificate error

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, unirest

I am using Unirest (java version) to make GET and POST request.But I encounter a problem when accessing SSL encrypted site , since my program is behind a corporate network and the network admin setup a firewall mapping for me. For example `foobar.com` is mapped to `56.1.89.12:4444`. But when I make request to the address, I will received the following ssl certificate error:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <56.1.89.12> != <www.foobar.com>
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:131)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:52)
```

I see `Unirest` has advance configuration to use custom `httpclient`.So I use

```
Unirest.setHttpClient(MyHttpClient.makeClient());
HttpResponse<String> res = null;
try {
    res = Unirest.get(urlstr).asString();
} catch (UnirestException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String jsonstr = res.getBody();
```

the `makeClient` method of `MyHttpClient` is:

```
public static HttpClient makeClient(){
 SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;
    try {
        // builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy(){
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        });
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                builder.build());
        httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
                sslsf).build();
        System.out.println("custom httpclient called");
        System.out.println(httpclient);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return httpclient;
}
```

the main idea is taken from [Ignoring SSL certificate in Apache HttpClient 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517538/ignoring-ssl-certificate-in-apache-httpclient-4-3)

But still this didn't work.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

I'm using "com.konghq:unirest-java:2.3.14“

There is a config now

```
Unirest.config().verifySsl(false);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
 SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    Unirest.setHttpClient(httpclient);
```

this worked for me

Comment: I found the same codes at https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/70

Answer (score 6):

This is how I finally solved my problem:

```
public static HttpClient makeClient(){
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
    try {
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, new MockSSLSocketFactory()));
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
    return httpclient;
}
```

I had been scratching for a whole day, I hope this could help someone.

Comment: What's a MockSSLSocketFactory?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/juddi/blob/master/juddi-client/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/v3/client/mapping/MockSSLSocketFactory.java

Answer (score 2):

the certificate error solution is a combination from a few places

- https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/70, where i started.
- http://literatejava.com/networks/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient-4-4/ very good explanation.
- http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl, solution for all versions.

### and a relatively complete example.

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class XXX {

    private static HttpClient unsafeHttpClient;

    static {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();

            unsafeHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();

        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient getClient() {
        return unsafeHttpClient;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            HttpClient creepyClient = RestUnirestClient.getClient();
            Unirest.setHttpClient(creepyClient);

            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://httpbin.org/get?show_env=1").asJson();
            System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());

        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Unirest does not have a native way to configure SSL, so providing a custom HttpClient instance looks like the only option.
Here is a solution, which does not use deprecated classes (like 'DefaultHttpClient') and works with self-signed certificates:

```
protected void prepareHttpsClient() {
    HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    try {
        String certificateStorage = <<yourCertStorageFileName>>;
        String certificatePassword = <<yourCertStoragePassword>>;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(
            new File(certificateStorage), certificatePassword.toCharArray(),
            new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1"}, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
        clientBuilder.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error configuring server certificates.", e);
    }
    HttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.build();
    Unirest.setHttpClient(httpClient);
}
```