# Is "ssl trust all certificates" enabled by default for Java URLConnection?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Is "ssl trust all certificates" enabled by default in case of Java URLConnection which is not the case with [Apache HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517538/ignoring-ssl-certificate-in-apache-httpclient-4-3)?

I'm using a self-signed certificate and is hosted locally (127.0.0.1).

Comment: No. By default it uses the system's trust store (which can be configured in various ways).

Comment: But, my system's trust store doesn't have the required certificate and still, it's able to make a successful request whereas Apache httpClient is throwing SSLHandshakeException.

Comment: You could use `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` to see what certificates are **really** used. By default the *cacerts* of the JRE is used, the difference could be use of SNI? I'd advice to check first what is realyl used.

Comment: Your system doesn't need the 'required certificate', unless it is self-signed. It only needs the certificate of one of the signers in the CA chain.

Comment: So show us your code.