# How do I provide create a CloseableHttpPipeliningClient that doesn't validate SSL certificates?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

I'm trying to use Apache HttpAsyncClient with HTTP pipelining support. I want to add a trust-all SSL strategy similar to what's discussed here [Ignoring SSL certificate in Apache HttpClient 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517538/ignoring-ssl-certificate-in-apache-httpclient-4-3) (and a bunch of other places). But I don't see any way to get a pipelining client builder using the custom SSLContext: the `HttpAsyncClients.createPipelining()` method doesn't return a builder, and `HttpAsyncClients.custom()` builder doesn't build a `ClosableHttpPipeliningClient`

Comment: Just... DON'T.  There is a reason it is hard to do this. It is to prevent people from writing code that breaks Internet security.  Bite the bullet and set up the necessary certificates.

Comment: This is for a test client in a test environment. This option exists on every HTTP client I've encountered so far, including Apache HttpClient, cURL, wget, and all browsers. It's very hard to imagine this limitation is there intentionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably do what you want

```
DefaultConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(IOReactorConfig.DEFAULT);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new TrustStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        return true;
    }
}).build();
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(
        ioReactor,
        RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>create()
                .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslContext))
                .build());
CloseableHttpPipeliningClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.createPipelining(cm);
httpClient.start();
```