# Connection to https server in Java vs Postman

Tags: java, https, certificate, postman

I am trying to connect to a server using HTTPS
The server has a self singed certificate (It is an internal server for testing)

When I use **postman** to hit the server , It is working fine (and shows a red indication about self signed certificate)

But when using from Java I get this error

> PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Postman **does not** have the certificate and it is still successful ? how come?

My Code (using feign):

```
SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
builder.loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLContext sslContext = builder.build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

Client feignClient = Client.Default(sslConnectionSocketFactory, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
...
```

Is there an option in Java not to use a certificate file (and not to install the certificate on the PC)

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187223/6793637

Comment: Yes, I was missing the part of using TrustManager that allows all